# Getting friends list from facebook order by name using graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios5, xcode4

I am getting the friends list by using graph api.I have searched a lot for getting the names in an order.Is there anyway(insted of sorting) for getting sorted names from graph api?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in FQL.

[SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me())%20ORDER%20BY%20name)

(Use https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=QUERY to run FQL queries in the Graph API.)

Comment: I tried the query,Its getting.I will try to implement that to the code .thanks

Comment: How to use this using graph api?